# Как извлечь значения из JSON файла по ключу?

Tags: python, json, парсер

Я получаю JSON файл с сервера. Mне надо с него взять определенные строки, в данном случае, вопрос и варианты ответов к нему, обработать их, и отправить боту.

Как отправить боту я понимаю, но как извлечь эти строки не понимаю, так как в начале JSON файл идет как словарь (`res`), потом там открывается список, а потом опять словарь.  Нужны строки:

```
"value": "Ухаживать за животными", "value": "Обслуживать машины", "value": "Вы предпочитаете".
```

```
res = {
  "description": "Выберите наиболее предпочтительный вариант ответа из предложенных",
  "id": 16,
  "questions": [
    {
      "answers": [
        {
          "id": 187,
          "value": "Ухаживать за животными"
        },
        {
          "id": 188,
          "value": "Обслуживать машины"
        }
      ],
      "component": "SelectOneAnswer",
      "direction": "row",
      "id": 96,
      "value": "Вы предпочитаете"
    },
    {
      "answers": [
        {
          "id": 189,
          "value": "Помогать больным людям, лечить их"
        },
        {
          "id": 190,
          "value": "Составлять таблицы, схемы, программы для вычислительных машин"
        }
      ],
      "component": "SelectOneAnswer",
      "direction": "row",
      "id": 97,
      "value": "Вы предпочитаете"
    },
    {
      "answers": [
        {
          "id": 191,
          "value": "Участвовать в оформлении книг, плакатов,  журналов"
        },
        {
          "id": 192,
          "value": "Следить за состоянием и развитием растений"
        }
      ],
      "component": "SelectOneAnswer",
      "direction": "row",
      "id": 98,
      "value": "Вы предпочитаете"
    },
    {
      "answers": [
        {
          "id": 193,
          "value": "Участвовать в оформлении книг, плакатов,  журналов"
        },
        {
          "id": 194,
          "value": "Следить за состоянием и развитием растений"
        }
      ],
      "component": "SelectOneAnswer",
      "direction": "row",
      "id": 99,
      "value": "Вы предпочитаете"
    }
      }
```

Я могу получить только все, что храниться в `questions`, делая так:
`a = res["questions"][0]` и выводя это через `print(a)`. Но а дальше, не знаю.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для того чтобы найти все значение по ключу `value` вне зависимости от глубины вложенности, можно воспользоваться модулем [dpath](https://pypi.org/project/dpath/):

```
import dpath.util as dp   #  pip install dpath


values = dp.values(res, "/questions/**/value")
```

---

результат:

```
In [13]: values
Out[13]:
['Ухаживать за животными',
 'Обслуживать машины',
 'Вы предпочитаете',
 'Помогать больным людям, лечить их',
 'Составлять таблицы, схемы, программы для вычислительных машин',
 'Вы предпочитаете',
 'Участвовать в оформлении книг, плакатов,  журналов',
 'Следить за состоянием и развитием растений',
 'Вы предпочитаете',
 'Участвовать в оформлении книг, плакатов,  журналов',
 'Следить за состоянием и развитием растений',
 'Вы предпочитаете']
```

---

> как правильно сделать что бы он разбивал, типа `Вы предпочитаете` - это
>   вопрос, а `Ухаживать за животными` и `Обслуживать машины` это два варианта
>   ответов, как правильно это обработать и вывести?

```
In [33]: dp.values(res, "questions/*/answers/**/value")
Out[33]:
['Ухаживать за животными',
 'Обслуживать машины',
 'Помогать больным людям, лечить их',
 'Составлять таблицы, схемы, программы для вычислительных машин',
 'Участвовать в оформлении книг, плакатов,  журналов',
 'Следить за состоянием и развитием растений',
 'Участвовать в оформлении книг, плакатов,  журналов',
 'Следить за состоянием и развитием растений']

In [34]: dp.values(res, "questions/*/value")
Out[34]:
['Вы предпочитаете',
 'Вы предпочитаете',
 'Вы предпочитаете',
 'Вы предпочитаете']
```

Comment: Можно еще один вопрос, а как правильно сделать что бы он разбивал, типа Вы предпочитаете - это вопрос, а Ухаживать за животными и Обслуживать машины это два варианта ответов, как правильно это обработать и вывести?

Comment: @AndreyDolgopolov, дополнил ответ

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Comment: Хм, делаю перебором с использованием вашего метода, взял json файл где больше значение, но мне почему то выводятся только первый 5.
count_questions = 0
for i in res:
    x = dp.values(res, "/questions/*/value")[count_questions]
    print("Вопрос: ", x)
    count_questions += 1

Comment: @AndreyDolgopolov, можете выложить ваш файл на какой-нибудь файлообменник?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/hKBFgJav

Answer (score 0):

```
a = res["questions"][0]["answers"][0]["value"]
```

И т д.